# Issue with pandas_datareader

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python world and working on to fetch the data with `pandas_datareader` but facing issue below.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
start = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 31)
AAPL = web.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', 'yahoo', start, end)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File
"C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py",
line 63, in get_data_yahoo
    raise ImmediateDeprecationError(DEP_ERROR_MSG.format('Yahoo Actions')) pandas_datareader.exceptions.ImmediateDeprecationError:
Yahoo Actions has been immediately deprecated due to large breaks in
the API without the introduction of a stable replacement. Pull
Requests to re-enable these data connectors are welcome.
```

See https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo shut down their API last year, therefore pandas_datareader depreciated (took out of use) the function. Try using [quandl](https://www.quandl.com/tools/python) instead.